# Exploited by newbie3viLc063s

Tags: linux, malware, php, firewalls, exploit

My debian server got exploited by some scriptiekiddie who used Newbie3viLc063
http://pastebin.com/jma8JRG1 . 
Scriptkiddie uploaded logo_php.png to my server (My permissions sucked :s) and he did run it as php file.

And I have few question:

How can I delete/block backdoor what it did. I did block port 55555 (script used it), removed .php file, changed root / www user's password. I also searched .cpp files and all files which have permission 777/755 (find / -mtime -40 -type f -perm 755. (that command found some files from /usr/bin)

Btw, did attacker fail somehow, because I found his his file (logo_php_png) from uploads folder, somehow it feels that it's pretty stupid to leave that file there...:D)

And I did run rkhunter, here is log: http://pastebin.com/syMnKVAL I'm not sure how I should react to those warnings, I did read that those can be false positives.

Comment: Runnig `rkhunter` without previous control is pointless. Your safest bet: reinstall

Answer (score 5):

In recommend you to reinstall the COMPLETE server, because after a successfull attack the server isn't in a trust relation anymore! Maybe there is more than just this backdoor.

Yes, it is a lot of time to set up a new server, but the only way to gain trust again.

Comment: Hmm okay, it is safe if I take backup from /var/www and then reupload it to new server?

Comment: @user2279808 Technically no, any files could be in there. Perhaps if you verify the files' age to be well before any signs of the breach. I would personally not reinstall the entire server, but from a security standpoint, it is the right thing to be advised.

Comment: @user2279808 if you consider taking a backup you still need to prove that the files are not containing dangerous code. at this point it depends on the webservice/website/application you are running...

Comment: @Luc file age isn't a secure indicator (still can be modified with e.g. touch)

Comment: @user2279808 you are seriously asking if you should re-upload the exploited code base?  Some people don't deserve to have a non-compromised system.

Comment: He did exploit my server with that .php file which I did remove, it  downloaded and compiled .cpp file, but /www/ should be clean. And of course I did check files which I did reupload. Also permissions are now much better set.

Comment: @user2279808 He was able to compile some binary on your server? Interesting php settings you have. What user does it even run as... Anyway, yeah perhaps I would actually just reinstall the whole thing then and check all files manually before putting them back.

Comment: Yeah, that what I did, he compiled .cpp file witch exec, and as I said, my permissions was really bad made x) Not php is running in safe mode, apache is running in right user and so on :P

Comment: PHP safe mode is deprecated, mostly due to how easy it is to bypass. Run PHP as a user which does *not* have access to server binaries, that'll solve some of your problems. Or just hire someone who knows how to.

Comment: Additional hint: most webservers run php-workers as nobody...